# 検索した文字列の検索色に2以上を設定すると検索結果やマーカーの色がおかしくなる不具合 (Ver. 21.6.0)

Tags: emeditor

Version 21.6.0 にアップデートしたところ、検索結果やマーカーの色がおかしくなりました。
Windows10でしか確認していませんが、複数の端末で同様に再現されたため、環境依存ではないと思います。

設定を変えながらテストしたところ、検索した文字列の[検索色]に、2以上の値を設定した際の動作に、バグがあるようです。
具体的には、以下設定の部分です。

[ツール] > [現在の設定のプロパティ] または [ツール] > [すべての設定のプロパティ] の [表示] で、
[検索した文字列(1)] を選択し、右側の [検索色(C):] を 2以上に設定し、
[背景色(B):]等を変更。

上記の設定で、「検索を2回以上行う」または「2つ以上追加したマーカーを切り替える」などの操作を行うと、検索結果やマーカーが設定した表示にならず、また、部分的に、[警告すべき文字]等の文字色になってしまうなどの不具合が発生します。

現在は、いったん、検索した文字列(1) だけに減らして使っていますが、検索色が複数設定できる点は、昔からEmEditorの一番の利点として活用してきた機能であり、早期の修正に期待いたします。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

この問題は、v21.6.901 で修正されています。ベータ版を含めて最新版に更新してお使いください。その後、v21.6.1 でも修正されました。

Comment: ベータ版を含めて最新版に更新したところ、修正されていることがわかりました。早急なご回答に感謝いたします。どうも有難うございました。

Comment: どういたしまして。よろしければ、左のチェックマークをクリックして、この回答を承認してください。